# Определить, сколько цифр, первая значащая цифра которых равна 2

Tags: pascal

Прошу помогите с задачей: 
Дано 100 целых чисел от 1 до 50. Определить, сколько среди них
цифр, первая значащая цифра которых равна 2

Comment: @Ендрю, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: "...сколько цифр, первая значащая цифра которых..." - это какая-то словесная каша.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i := 1 to 100 do
   if (a[i] >= 10) then
      if (a[i] div 10 = 2) then inc(count)
   else
      if (a[i] = 2) then inc(count);
{ count = количество таких чисел }
```

Comment: работа за автора. вы получили знак "медвежья услуга".

Comment: @Yura Ivanov дайте чуваку заработать очков

Comment: Если @Ендрю такое решить не смог, то это ему вряд ли поможет, а вот посидеть и разобраться в том, что я написал, а не забить на задание может быть и поможет.

Comment: @samoilow, за последние две-три недели таких вопросов на хэшкоде было около сотни, некоторые писались непосредственно с экзамена. то, что вы написали не поможет спрашивающему. послать за Фигурновым (или по кому там нынче паскаль изучают?) было бы более верным ответом.

Comment: @samoilow не лукавьте - вы же прекрасно понимаете, что если чувак не может решить такой пример, то он не станет сидеть и разбираться с вашим кодом. Он просто сдаст его преподу, после чего забудет о паскале и программировании до следующей сессии

Answer (score 0):

Или так чуть короче

```
  Count:=0;
  For I:=1 To 100 Do
    If IntToStr(A[I])[1]='2' Then Inc(Count);
```